# Rails 4 + ActiveAdmin + Devise Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying ActiveAdmin with devise and i've generated the devise views (sessions, registrations, and so on).

Without ActiveAdmin when i create `/layouts/devise/sessions.html.erb` i can change the devise layout which calls the above mentioned views, but this does not happen with ActiveAdmin.

My routes.rb includes:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

And my devise.rb initializer:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

Been looking in [the docs](http://activeadmin.info/) but i dont know where to start :(

Anyone have faced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally,
Creating a file called `layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb` did the trick!